# html5 datalist different color for different options

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, styles

I have the following code example:

```
 <label>
  Enter your favorite cartoon character:<br />
  <input type="text" name="favCharacter" list="characters" maxlength="50" style="width:95%;">
   <datalist id="characters">
    <option value="Homer Simpson">
    <option value="Bart">
    <option value="Fred Flinstone">
   </datalist>
 </label>
```

Is it possible to style "Bart" option, for example paint it with yellow -
style="color: yellow" ?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers define their own styles for these elements (datalist, select, option) and you can't style them.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `CSS` with using the attribute access:

```
option[value="Bart"] {
    color: yellow;
}
```

this would change the color to yellow for `<option value="Bart">` Tags

Comment: it's not such easy, it's surprising that someone has already upvoted this.